# How do I play the T-Bone missions?

Tags: watch-dogs

Since completing the main campaign for Watch Dogs I've bought the season pass which gives a few more missions, a digital trip and a "new" campaign featuring the hacker T-Bone. Thing is, I can't find out how you actually play them - there's nothing in the in-game Additional Content menu and some online sites say "released August"...with it being nearly the end of August I still can't see them.

Have the missions been released yet, and if so, how can I play them?

Comment: Which platform?

Comment: @DrakaSAN, PC through Uplay.

Comment: I have a similar problem on PS3, DLC downloaded throught Uplay just... Don t download (or install correctly). After the download, they still appear has "to be downloaded" in the Uplay app. I think you have a similar problem and should try to contact Uplay to ask them what could be the  problem.

Answer (score 1):

The new Bad Blood DLC is starting to appear as downloadable, I only just got this today 27/9/14

Answer (score 1):

you have to download both part one and two and then it will say Watch_Dogs Bad Blood New and Aiden Pierce new/load (At least on xbox 360 and One)